# jenkins passing AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding to slave node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline which needs to run on a slave node. I curently have issues with passing Variables set by plugin withCredentials. When I try to use them on the slave node they are empty, but they work on the master.

Here is the pipeline snippet.

```
#!groovy
@Library('sharedPipelineLib@master') _

pipeline {
  agent { node
    { label 'jenkins-slave-docker' }
  }
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout(true)
    }
    environment {
      sonar = credentials('SONAR')
    }
    stages {
      stage('Checkout') {
        steps {
          cleanWs()
          script {
            checkout scm
            }
          }
        }


      stage('Deploy backend') {
        steps {
            script {
                withCredentials([
                        [
                                $class           : 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                                credentialsId    : 'AWS_ACCOUNT_ID_DEV',
                                accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEV',
                                secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV'
                        ],
                        [
                                $class           : 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                                credentialsId    : 'AWS_ACCOUNT_ID_DNS',
                                accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DNS',
                                secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DNS'
                        ]
                ]){
                  sh '''
                    echo "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEV\\n$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV\\n\\n" | aws configure --profile profile_705229686812
                    echo "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DNS\\n$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DNS\\n\\n" | aws configure --profile profile_417752960097

                  '''
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And the log

```
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEV or $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV or $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DNS or $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DNS
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh


echo '\n\n\n'
aws configure --profile profile_705229686812
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AWS Secret Access Key [None]: 
EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was again echo cmd. I had to uses printf instead, cause echo adds newline which causes to fail.